# debugging on usb connected device

Tags: android

I am trying to debug on a USB connection to several different Sony tablets (particularly the P, which is listed as supported).  I can debug on a smart phone, but the tablet doesn't show up as a connected device when I try to run my app in Eclipse.  I have checked that the settings of the tablet have Applications->Unknown sources, and Applications->Development->USB Debugging

Comment: "doesn't show up as a connected devic" looks driver is missing ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly common problem. You basically don't have the drivers you need for USB debugging.

There are a few different ways I've had to obtain drivers for phones. The first way you should attempt is to go into the Android SDK and AVD manager and download the Google USB driver debug package.

This may or may not give you the driver you need. If it doesn't you will have to do one of two things. One, add the device details to the driver file you just downloaded. Generally these will be posted on forums/boards discussing your Tablet/Phone type. Secondly, you can download a different driver from another source like the Tab/Phone manufacturer.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGojjF3eETo) a Youtube video how to install  Sony Tablet S & P

Answer (score 0):

Or the app you are developing has set the target higher than your tablet supports. Then it also won`t show up in the AVD Manager.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wont get proper drivers for your tablet you can try adb over network.

1. Connect your device to wifi as well as your computer.
2. turn on ADB over network in Options for developers (maybe some ROM dont support it). Eventualy you can enable this using specific commands on your tablet.
3. on your computer run terminal and use: `adb connect <ip>:<port>` where `<ip>` refers to IP of your tablet and `<port>` refers to port on which adb is listening (usually 5555).
4. run `adb devices` to verify that device is connected